# Why does this integral converge?

Tags: analysis

$$ \int_0^{\infty } \frac{\ln(t)}{1+t^2} dt$$

That is an example from my book. No explination given.
How to show that it is converging?

Comment: Correct your question.

Comment: in my opinion its rather divergent?

Comment: @wondering1123: Math is not about having opinions ...

Comment: Split the range at $1$ ... looks like the  the Catalan constant minus the Catalan Constant ... $\color{red}{0}$.

Comment: There's a quick solution here -> https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1613375/254075

Comment: So it seems your book has a chapter named "A Converging Integral," and the first (and only) page of this chapter is just this formula in the middle of the page with nothing else around it. But if that's _not_ what's in your book, when posting a question like this you should explain the context in which the integral appears (what are you told about it, what techniques are being discussed beforehand, etc.) to give clues about what kind of answer you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the integral into two $[0,\infty) \rightarrow [0,1] \cup [1,\infty)$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(t)}{1+t^2} dt + \int_1^{\infty} \frac{\ln(t)}{1+t^2} dt
\end{eqnarray*}
Now substitute $t=\frac{1}{u}$ into the second integral & observe that we get the first integral but with three minus signs ... so they cancel out to give $\color{red}{0}$. It is important to observe that on their own each of these integrals evaluates to the Catalan constant & therefore this cancellation is justified.

Answer (score 3):

Let 
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\log t}{1+t^2}dt = A\\
\int_1^\infty\frac{\log t}{1+t^2}dt = B\\
$$
The integral in question is then $A+B$.

Manipulate $B$ by the substitution 
$$
t = \frac1u\\
dt = -\frac1{u^2}du\\
\log t = -\log u\\
t\to 1 \implies u\to 1\\
t\to\infty \implies u\to 0
$$ so that
$$
B = \int_{u=1}^{u=0}\frac{(-\log u)}{1+u^{-2}}\left( -\frac1{u^2}\right)du = 
- \int_{u=0}^{u=1}\frac{(\log u)}{u^2(1+u^{-2})}du = 
- \int_{0}^{1}\frac{(-\log u)}{u^2+1}du = -A
$$
Thus the integral in the problem is $A+B = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly

$$\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln(t)}{1+t^2}\,dt<\int_1^\infty\frac{\sqrt{t}}{1+t^2}\,dt<\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{t^{3/2}}\,dt$$

converges.

Then for

$$ \int_0^1\frac{\ln(t)}{1+t^2}\,dt $$

substituting $u=\dfrac{1}{t}$ yields

$$ -\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln(u)}{1+u^2}\,du $$

which we already know to converge.